# Why was the Union Budget presented in the Lok Sabha (lower house) instead of the Rajya Sabha (upper house)?

Tags: parliament, india, budget, bicameral

Why was the Union Budget presented in the Lok Sabha (lower house) instead of the Rajya Sabha (upper house)?

Recently **The Union Budget of India** for 2021–2022 was presented by the Finance Minister, Nirmala Sitharaman on 1 February 2021.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20210202032303/https://www.thehindu.com/business/budget/highlights-of-union-budget-2021-22/article33713457.ece)

Comment: Was there something unusual about this case? Or are you asking more generally why budgets are presented in the Lok Sabha?

Answer (score 2):

Conventionally, in India, the directly-elected lower house is more powerful in a lot of matters than the indirectly elected upper house. One such case is the passing of [money bills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_bill#India).

The Union budget is a [money bill and by law, money bills can only be introduced in the lower house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_bill#India). The upper house can make amendments, but they cannot discard the bill. The amendments too are non-binding on the lower house.